# Missing record in mysql when saving a request from Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Table**

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('confirmation_code');
        $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(config('access.users.confirm_email') ? false : true);
        $table->string('street')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'street',
    'city',]
```

**Controller**

```
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $user->street = $request->street;
    $user->city = $request->city;
    $user->save();
```

When I run my function in postman with `return response()->json($user);` I get

```
{
 "id": 5,
 "name": null,
 "email": "1@1.com",
 "status": 0,
"confirmed": false,
 "street": "Ulloa",
 "city": null,}
```

When I `dd($request->all())` I get

```
array:2 [
"city" => "Woodside"
 "street" => "Ulloa"
]
```

**Question**

why the "city" value does is null in MySQL database ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got `city_` key in request, but not `city`, that's why `$request->city` is empty.

Comment: sorry that was a typo it's without the underscore